# how to create data in one to many relationship in laravel 6?

Tags: laravel

Kegiatan.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Kegiatan extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['kegiatan'];
    protected $table = 'kegiatan';

    public function galeri()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Galeri::class);
    }
}
```

Galeri.php

```
class Galeri extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['galeri'];
    protected $table = 'galeri';

    public function kegiatan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Kegiatan::class);
    }
}
```

form.blade.php

```
<form action="galeri" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 ml-3">
            <input type="text" name="namakegiatan"
                class="form-control form-control-lg text-center @error('namakegiatan') is-invalid @enderror"
                placeholder="Nama kegiatan" value="{{ old('namakegiatan') }}" autocomplete="off">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 ml-3">
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" name="fotokegiatan[]"
                    class="custom-file-input custom-file-input @error('fotokegiatan') is-invalid @enderror"
                    id="customFile" id="customFile" multiple>
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Pilih foto kegiatan...</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 ml-3">
            <button class="btn btn-dark btn-block" type="submit">
                <i class="mdi mdi mdi-content-save"> </i> Simpan</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

the question is, how to save one 'kegiatan' with many 'galeri' (photo) in a controller using one to many relationship?

which I expect more or less like the example below:

kegiatan table:

```
ID   KEGIATAN
1    kegiatan1
```

galeri table:

```
ID   GALERI       KEGIATAN_ID
1    foto1.jpg    1
2    foto2.jpg    1
3    foto3.jpg    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your controller in store method, you'd do something like this:

```
foreach($request->fotokegiatan as $obj)
{
  $kegiatan->galeri()->save($obj)
}
```

Can't provide you with much more code, since I can't see your controller, but this should guide you to the solution.

Comment: thank you sir, I did not include the controller because I was confused about what I should show.

oh yeah where did the `$kegiatan` variable come from?

Comment: No problem, hope I could help you. As for `$kegiatan` variable, that could be your `Kegiatan` model: `$kegiatan = new Kegiatan`

Comment: I'm glad. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

To create entities

```php
$kegiatan = App\Kegiatan::create($createData);
```

or to update entities:

```php
$kegiatan = App\Kegiatan::find($id);
$kegiatan = $kegiatan->update($updateValueArray);
```

To create multiple entities

```php
$kegiatan->galeri()->create($arrayGaleriData);
```

Comment: thank you very much sir, this is very helpful.

oh yes, how do I if I want to delete? whether by using

`$kegiatan = $kegiatan->delete($updateValueArray);` ?